# Get maps location without clicking on it

Tags: r

I have a url/api from google which allocate the location as per the latitude and longitude as shown below.
Here the user have to click on the below link to navigate to the maps.
So wanted to check if we can have location ready without clicking on it

```
HTML('<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=50.89090819,14.86667618" target="_blank">Google Maps</a>')
```

Comment: can you clarify your question please: Are you trying to extract the longitude / latitude coordinates from that URL string?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
h <- read_html(htmltools::HTML('<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=50.89090819,14.86667618" target="_blank">Google Maps</a>'))
h %>%
  html_elements("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>%
  gsub(".*\\?q\\=(.*)$", "\\1", .) %>% 
  str_split(., ",", simplify=TRUE) %>% 
  as.numeric(.)
#> [1] 50.89091 14.86668
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>